# Shapes.AddOLEObject method not working in PowerPoint 2013 (32bit and 64bit)?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, webbrowser-control, powerpoint-2013

I am using the following code to add web browser control to PowerPoint slide,

```
Set oShp = oSld.Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=200, Height:=300, Classname:="Shell.Explorer", Link:=msoFalse)
```

The above code works fine in all PowerPoint versions except **PowerPoint 2013 (32bit and 64bit)**. I get the following error message,

[image]

In **PowerPoint 2010 (32bit and 64bit)** the web browser control is added but the control is black until viewing it in Slide Show. Then it gets refreshed.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the error because Web Browser Control are made obsolete in Office 2013 for security reasons.

There is a workaround HOWEVER, it will put your machines at risk of vulnerability attacks

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2793374

Comment: Thanks. This may be the issue. I'll go through this and get back to you.

Comment: It works. But, I have one question: When the OLEObject Web Browser Control (opening PDF file) is added the shape becomes black. Do you know why? It becomes normal when view it in Slide View mode.

Comment: I suppose that's how Shapes are colored by default. You can try adding the optional parameter DisplayAsIcon:=True, which displays the shape into an icon. Hope everything helped

Comment: I hope I've earned your bounty :)

Comment: Thanks for your help sop far. If given "DisplayAsIcon:=True" it always only shows the icon and not the content. Anyway thanks again.